# PostgreSQL jsonb field in ActiveRecord belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Can I use a jsonb field as a foreign_key in a belongs_to association? Something along the lines of:

```
belongs_to :product, class_name: "Product",  foreign_key: "data ->'product_id'"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References can be defined only between columns (or groups of columns), as it is stated in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html):

> FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn
>   [, ... ] ) ]

Comment: I honestly don't see how foreign key *constraints* limitations are relevant to the question...  Yes, this would mean that you can't guarantee referential *integrity*, but I don't see how it means that rails couldn't still build a relationship *if* that's not a concern.  `SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN instructions ON products.id = instructions.data->'product_id'` would still be valid SQL without the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, no?

Comment: @SampsonCrowley - The declaration refers to a foreign key. Per [the documentation:](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations) *(...) by declaring that one model belongs_to another, you instruct Rails to maintain Primary Key-Foreign Key information between instances of the two models.*

Comment: that still has nothing to do with the database itself; the keyword there being *instances* of the two models. If I create a table with a column `product_id`, without *any* form of `FOREIGN KEY`, rails has no problem using that column to create associations and the correct queries. I guess my point being your link to the *PostgreSQL* docs have nothing to to with the ability of rails `belongs_to`/`has_many` to configure and create associations, otherwise polymorphic associations would be impossible

Comment: The quoted sentence clearly shows that *belongs_to* is implemented by a reference (*primary key - foreign key*) in a database. Other associations may be implemented in a different way.

Comment: Nope, it is in **no** way required to maintain referencial integrity at the DB level. I can 100% guarantee you ActiveRecord does **zero** checking to see if a foreign key constraint exists. the ONLY reason that the asker's code doesn't work, is **ActiveRecord** expects the key to be an *attribute* on the *model*. Straight from the same link you provided in the comments: *If you wish to enforce referential integrity at the database level, add the foreign_key: true option to the ‘reference’ column declarations above.*  It's completely optional whether to make the column an actual foreign key

Comment: Ok, but the implementation has to be ready to handle the database foreign key (in the case of *foreign_key: true* option). The ActiveRecord requirement reflects database restrictions

Comment: the `foreign_key: true` option has nothing to do with the association directly. that is *only* applicable to the *migration*, i.e. `#references` method. They are two completely separate modules that do not require method interop in any way. Your link to the *PostgreSQL* docs still has nothing to do with the question. a more relevant link would be the link you placed in the comments; or this issue, that mentions raw sql is not supported, which is the *real* reason: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29607

Comment: It is a matter of looking at ActiveRecord (or ORMS in general). In my opinion, they are a database overlays and their structure reflects the capabilities of the underlying database (note that the concept of foreign keys is common to different database systems). You look at ActiveRecord as a stand-alone product that can optionally use databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217412/discussion-between-sampson-crowley-and-klin).

Answer (score 4):

you can use [activerecord-json-associations](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/activerecord-jsonb-associations) to use PostgreSQL JSONB fields to store association information of your models

Answer (score 0):

As was discussed in comments to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891336/198424) that @klin gave , it not possible to do in ActiveRecord out of the box.

However I came up with a maintable approach that works much better, in a similar situation in my project.

I'm utilizing a database feature (if you can  control underlying DB) - Generated or Virtual columns are well suited for this task

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN product_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(data->>'product_id' AS BIGINT)) STORED;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "index_orders_on_product_id" ON "cq_shopify"."orders" ("product_id");
```

Now you are making DB do what it does best - store data and run essentially a stored procidure to maintain data integrity.

Since you now have a virtual or generate field called `product_id` you can use normal `belongs_to :products` in your Rails app

To keep this in you project - just add it as a migration to your code.