# Rails Postgres hstore or jsonb to store many to many relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There is a table 'Products' with columns (id, tile, price, description, shop_id, timestamps)
Column price and shop_id are dynamic. The rest of column are static.

Also there is a table 'Shops' with columns (id, name, timestamps).

Shop has many products. Product can migrate among all shops and products.shop_id can be blank.

I want to have history about which products a shop had. For example, yesterday shop had products and their prices. Day before yesterday shop had other products and/or other their prices. So I want to have something like

'ShopHistory' (id, data, date, timestamps), where data is hstore or json. So it should have hash like { key: value}, where key is id of product and value is its current price. But I would like to joins data column with products in order to know about title and description of products. I have no idea how to do that.
It looks like ShopHistory is a join table between shop and products, but all information are stored in one row.

Could we help me? Maybe anyone knows a better way to implement all of this. Any thought and articles are welcome.

Thanks!

P.S. I use rails(ActiveRecord) and PostgreSQL, but answers from guys who know only Postgres are good for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get your intent, but frankly I don't think it's going to work out for you in a straightforward, easy way. (As a rule of thumb, in ruby and in rails, if it isn't straightforward, you're probably not doing it the ruby/rails way).

Why do I know this? Because I tried before to do a very similar thing to what you want to do with an hstore, with no luck:

[Can I use ActiveRecord relationships with fields from an Hstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704936/can-i-use-activerecord-relationships-with-fields-from-an-hstore/)

As a better solution (what worked out for me in the end), please consider making an intermediate model to match `Shop`s to `Product`s, (maybe you'll want to name this intermediate model something like `Shop_product`, with a join table `shops_products`, but the name is up to you) then join both models using the intermediate model with a `has_many` `through:` relationship as detailed here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Something like:

```
class Shop << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :products, through: :shop_products
end

class ShopProduct << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :shops, through: :products
```

(There's more info about how to create all of that in the link, I recommend that read)

Now you will have an association set up, so you can get:

```
Shop.find_by_id(1).products
Product.find_by_id(1).shops
```

Finally, I think you can use ActiveRecord **scopes** to solve the second computational problem that you need to solve (that is, find the price per day in the past).

Scopes will allow you, ideally, to do queries like:

```
Shop.products.active_yesterday

class Product << ActiveRecord::Base

  scope active_yesterday -> { where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, 1.day.ago.end_of_day) }

  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :shops, through: :shop_products
end
```

All of my code is not production-ready and not tested, but I think my examples and links should be enough to get you on the right path.

Let me know if you need more help and I can try to help.

Comment: I'm using JSON instead of ActiveRecord for a specific case. I wrote a ruby library object to handle that logic.