# Cast jsonb foreign key on Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Using Rails 6, I'm trying to set a has_many association with a join to a postgres jsonb column.

```
class Form
  has_many :automation_triggers, foreign_key: "preferences->>'form_id'"
end
```

This results in the error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = jsonb)`

The foreign key needs be cast as an integer to resolve the error so the query should look like:

```
SELECT "automation_triggers".* FROM "automation_triggers" INNER JOIN forms ON (forms.id = (automation_triggers.preferences->'form_id')::int)
```

Is there a way to apply a cast to a has_many association foreign key? or write a custom join query for the association?

Comment: I was hoping for something built-in, but I think it's time to build a gem... will update here when done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL jsonb field in ActiveRecord belongs\_to association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889252/postgresql-jsonb-field-in-activerecord-belongs-to-association)

Comment: @SampsonCrowley have you manged to build a gem?

Comment: @Taras yes, actually. Check out the associate_jsonb gem. I haven't touched it in a long time, but it still should be completely functional for rails 6 (haven't updated it for rails 7)